# In exported Jupyter Notebooks, how do I disable the ¶?

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When I export a notebook to html, my headings have a ¶ (pilcrow) at the end; how do I turn that off?

Here is an example command I am using:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --template basic Untitled.ipynb
```

where the notebook just contains a cell with a markdown heading and text:

```
# Here I am

Rock you like a hurricane
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a way to disable this. But there's a good reason it exists: It provides an easy way for users to link to a particular heading. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: I'm generating hundreds of static reports from the notebooks and the pilcrow looks weird. My users can't link in to the html anyway, it's embedded.

Comment: There isn't currently an easy way to disable it, but if you want to hack your local copy of the code, the line that adds that pilcrow is [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/68a3925efef5c304c2c8682ad05cac9560c4173a/nbconvert/filters/markdown_mistune.py#L105).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. That looks like it will fix legacy headers; do you think it will also fix markdown headers?

Comment: I take that back, I guess `MarkdownWithMath` calls into `IPythonRenderer` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported as a config option:

```
c.HTMLExporter.anchor_link_text = '' # disable pilcrow, requires nbconvert >= 5.2
```

OLD:

I was able to turn off pilcrows by patching the markdown renderer:

```
import mistune
import nbconvert
nbconvert.filters.markdown_mistune.IPythonRenderer.header = mistune.Renderer.header
```

This seems pretty hacky though.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. My work-around was to realise that the pilcrow has its own class in the html, which is different to the headings it follows, and add the following to the css to make the pilcrow have font size 0, which removes the pilcrow from the rendered page.

```
.anchor-link{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

You could also make the text-color the same as the background, or a number of other things to make the Pilcrow effectively disappear.

Comment: I can't use css in HTML email :(